# import org.springframework cannot be resolved on imported Spring Initializr project in Eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-initializr

**This should be working out of the box. Why doesn't it?**

It seems like I can't import a Spring Boot Gradle project into Eclipse. It doesn't recognize any of the dependencies. This should be easy. Why is this not working?

Here is the configuration of my Spring Initilizr project:

[image: broken piece of crap]

Then do the following:

1. Import
2. Existing gradle project
3. Select the root directory
4. Import

It comes up and doesn't recognize the dependencies in the project:

[image: busted]

Here's what I've tried:

0. Stack overflow (most of the examples are for maven and say refresh dependency tree)
1. Cleaning and building the project
2. Building the project
3. Manually checking that the dependencies are there in the build.gradle file
4. Installing Spring Tools into eclipse
5. Converting project to faceted form (Java)
6. reran the initilizr with as a WAR file

Depicted is my gradle.build file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It's the most stupid solution in the world.

When you extract the file from the .zip the initilizr creates, you can't use the root directory.

example/example/blah/blah/blah...

You have to go into the extracted directory and up one directory.

So go into example, and import the example file within that directory,.

That's why it was busted.